# Replace DbProviderServices in DbMigrationsConfiguration?

Tags: entity-framework-6.1

In EF6.1.3 I am trying to replace current DbProviderService with a new Provider Service. In `DbConfiguration` this works by adding code to the Loaded event:

```
Loaded += (sender, args) =>
                args.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>(
                (s, _) => new SomeProviderServices(s, myhandler));
```

If I try to do this in `DbMigrationsConfiguration` constructor

```
DbConfiguration.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
                args.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>(
                (s, _) => new SomeProviderServices(s, myhandler));
```

I get an exception stating that EF has already been loaded and I cannot change the Loaded event handler by now.

What should be my course of actions in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are some actions you could take. I for instance have modified the web config:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MyNamespace.Assembly1.MyConfigurationClass, MyNamespace.Assembly1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b254a7d323adadef">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your Loaded event at your application startup.
In a MVC application you can put this line of code in Global.asax Application_Start (MVC 4) or Startup Configuration (OWIN) Methods:

```
 DbConfiguration.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
            args.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>(
            (s, _) => new SomeProviderServices(s, myhandler));
```

Loaded is a static event in DBConfiguration, so when your Entity Framework starts you'll have this event executed.